# Ubuntu 16.10 Bluetooth not detected

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 16.10

Bluetooth recently (today) stopped working. It's detected and the applet no longer appears.

Doesn't appear in `rfkill list`

```
brian:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Doesn't appear in `lspci`

```
brian:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

dmesg output:

```
brian:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[  341.111791] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[  341.111803] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  341.111805] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  341.111807] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  341.111810] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  871.825132] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  871.825133] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  871.825136] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Tried `service bluetooth restart` with no messages. `bluetoothctl` hangs on the "connecting..." message.

I also verified that the adapter is not disabled in the BIOS (there isn't even an option for this).

What else can I try to diagnose this issue?